# Como dar permissão para gravar ficheiros temporários na pasta c\windows\tmp com laravel 5.4?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

Gostaria que me ajudassem a resolver este problema:
Como dar permissão para gravar ficheiros temporários na pasta c\windows\tmp com laravel 5.4?

Comment: Recomendo tentar utilizar variável de ambiente %TEMP% , qualquer diretório dentro do Windows, vai precisar elevar o usuário

Comment: Como faço isso? Sou principiante em programação web, agradeço uma explicação.

Comment: Não conheço laravel, mas é PHP né? Qual o propósito de usar um diretório temporário?

Comment: Esse erro está dando ao fazer upload de imagem para uma pasta no "public" e depois salvar o caminho no banco.

Answer (score -1):

**Achei a resposta:**

Botão direito em Computador, Propriedades, Configurações avançadas do Sistema, Avançados, Variáveis de ambiente, não mexe na parte de cima "Variavel de utilizador para", mas sim na parte de baixo "Variavel do sistema", editar, localiza TEMP e TMP, substitua pelos valores abaixo.

TEMP = %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp

TMP = %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp

Comment: Acredito que não seja essa a solução pro seu problema, a ideia das variáveis de ambiente era apenas para não usar c\windows\temp. Como é servidor web, e você vai armazenar as imagens em arquivo, e o diretório no banco, recomendo pensar melhor na solução, criando um diretório apenas para as imagens dentro da raiz do site ou armazenar as imagens no banco